# I need help replacing a russian phrase in Perl Windows

Tags: perl

`perl -pi -e "s/\x22message\x22\s+\x22Боже, ты посмотри вокруг, что происходит!\x22/\x22message\x22 \x22\x22/g;" "D:\Sav\scripts\chat_wheel.txt"`

There is nothing wrong with this command except for the russian text portion that i want to remove

> Боже, ты посмотри вокруг, что происходит!

When i run it in cmd.exe, i get the following error message.

> Nested quantifiers in regex; marked by <-- HERE in
> m/\x22message\x22\s+\x22??? <-- HERE ?, ?? ???????? ??????, ???
> ??????????!\x22/ at -e line 1.

So, how do i replace the russian phrase while keeping the command as a one-liner? is it even possible?

My console uses CP 65001 (UTF-8). [From `Win32::GetConsoleCP()`]
My Active Code Page (ACP) is 1252 [From `Win32::GetACP()`].
My file is encoded using UTF-8.

Comment: Please provide the output of `perl -Mv5.10 -MWin32 -e"say for Win32::GetConsoleCP(), Win32::GetACP()"`

Comment: `@ikegami` Yeah, I tried entering the command chcp 65001 into cmd, then it said 'Active code page: 65001' and I entered the code again, but it doesn't appear to be a cmd problem, it appears to be a perl code problem, and the file's encoding is UTF-8.

Comment: `@ikegami` And this is the result of the command you just gave me
65001
1252

Comment: I don't think the tags work if you put them in backticks. But I noticed anyway. Answering.

Comment: What if you add `-CDA` to the arguments? `perl -CDA -pi ...`. It treats files and command line arguments as utf-8 encoded (see perlrun for details)

Comment: I tried it and got the same Nested quantifiers error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Б` is being replaced by `?`. This is because it's not supported by the console's code page, by the active code page, or both.

Your console's code page is set to 65001, or UTF-8. Your console can therefore handle any character in the Unicode character set. The problem is obviously not here.

Each Windows system call that deal with strings come in two varieties. A "W"ide variety that uses UTF-16le, and an "A"NSI variety which uses the Active Code Page. If Perl used the "W" interface to grab its command line parameters, we wouldn't be having this problem. Perl instead uses the "A" interface for this (and all other) system call.

This means Perl can only accept command-line arguments which can be represented by the Active Code Page. In your case, it's [1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), and the cp1252 character set doesn't include any cyrillic characters.

Assuming we don't want to replace every character with an escape (like how you replaced double-quotes with `"`), we're going to need do something different.

Since we can't pass the script using an argument, we'll need to provide it using a file rather than using `-e`. Or via a pipe.

```
echo s/"message"\s+"\KБоже(?=")// | perl -i -p - file.txt
```

A better but more drastic solution would be to [change Perl's ACP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) to 65001.

---

There's a second issue.

Perl expects its source code to be encoded using (8-bit clean) ASCII unless you provide `use utf8;`. So while you think you're passing `s/...Боже...//`, you're really passing `s/...\xD0\x91\xD0\xBE\xD0\xB6\xD0\xB5...//`.

This works out ok, in part because your don't decode your input file either. But it can lead to surprises. For example, `"Б" =~ /^[Бж]\z/` (`"\xD0\x91" =~ /^[\xD0\x91\xD0\xB6]\z/`) would return false!

To fix this in a script, you'd use

```perl
use utf8;                              # Source code is using UTF-8.
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';   # Terminal provides & expects UTF-8.
```

`-C` will do here.

```
echo s/"message"\s+"\KБоже(?=")// | perl -i -C -p - file.txt
```

Comment: This is really cool. this worked perfectly for me, thank you for taking the time to explain everything in detail. i only had to tweak it slightly because the command like this
`echo s/"message"\s+"\Боже, ты посмотри вокруг, что происходит!(?=")// | perl -i -C -p - "D:\Sav\scripts\chat_wheel.txt"`. was producing this result for me `"`. Then i just tweaked it a little bit to make it look like this
`echo s/"message"\s+"\Боже, ты посмотри вокруг, что происходит!(?=")/\x22message\x22 \x22/ | perl -i -C -p - "D:\Sav\scripts\chat_wheel.txt"`. to give me this `"message" ""`

Comment: It didn't work because you removed the `\K`. (You do need to re-add `, ты посмотри вокруг, что происходит!` of course. I removed it for readability.)

Comment: Omg you are right, i didn't even notice it i assumed it was part of the russian phrase lol my bad, it works smoothly now and as intended ;p

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but if i may, how can i more efficiently remove a large number of lines containing russian phrases in the same file while avoiding opening the file with each one-line command?
I have thousands of lines saved in a batch file like this, but i believe some of them do not apply due to how quickly the file "chat wheel.txt" opens and saves a lot.

`echo s/"message"\s+"\KЁ! А? А? Что?!(?=")// | perl -i -C -p - "D:\Sav\scripts\chat_wheel.txt"`.
`echo s/"message"\s+"\KА нет, нет, ДА!(?=")// | perl -i -C -p - "D:\Sav\scripts\chat_wheel.txt"`.
..etc

Comment: `(?:phrase1|phrase2|phrase3|...)`

Comment: Srry i didn't know how to use it X)
`echo s/"message"\s+"\KKЁ! А? А? Что?! | /"message"\s+"\KА нет, нет, ДА! | /"message"\s+"\KБоже, ты посмотри вокруг, что происходит!(?=")// | perl -i -C -p - "D:\Sav\scripts\chat_wheel.txt"`
Could you please give me an example of where i should put the last code you gave me?

Comment: instead of `KБоже`

Comment: Srry, i still need a little more help to get it to work. it replaces the first phrase correctly, but when i add the second phrase, it gives me errors.

`echo s/\x22message\x22\s+\x22\K(?:Боже, ты посмотри вокруг, что происходит!|KЁ! А? А? Что?!\x22)// | perl -i -C -p - "D:\Sav\scripts\chat_wheel.txt"`.

Also, the tag feature does not work for me. when i type the tag and press enter, it disappears, so i can't tag you. that's also why i tried putting it in backticks before to keep it from disappearing.

Comment: The tag is removed because you're commenting on my own post

Comment: Part of the problem is that `|` has special meaning to `cmd`. Some escaping will be necessary. I think `^|`?

Comment: I added it, but nothing changed, and the text is still not being replaced.

Comment: Did you check if the echo produces the correct code? ...And you do know `?` is special in regex, right?

Comment: Yeah it does, and this is the error message i'm getting
`'KЁ!' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Let's just say i had a feeling it did, but i don't think it's the problem yet. i'm also a complete noob at perl, but i'm having a great time learning what it can do so far ;)

Comment: yeah, it's a shell quoting issue. `|` is being interpreted just like the exiting `|` in the command.

Comment: I believe it was a quote issue because i kept messing with them until the command looked like this and was sent in `cmd` with no errors, so it now works without issue ;D. `echo s/"message"\s+"\K(?:Боже, как это больно!|Боже, ты посмотри вокруг, что происходит!|Вот Это Врыв!|Да? Да? Да? Нет.|Жил до конца, умер как герой)"/\x22/ | perl -i -C -p - "D:\Sav\scripts\chat_wheel.txt"`.